# android's SparseIntArray does it automatically autobox keys

Tags: android, hashmap

I'd like to know the difference in performance between the two pieces of similar methods. One will use the Integer java wrapper and one will use primitive int.

1st one using Integer:

```
public SparseIntArray readCountArray(Cursor cursor){
        SparseIntArray countMap=new SparseIntArray();
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
//notice the Integer objects here
            Integer id=cursor.getInt(ID_INDEX);
            Integer count=cursor.getInt(TASK_COUNT_INDEX);
            countMap.put(id,count);
        }
        return countMap;
    }
```

and here is the primitive example:

```
    public SparseIntArray readCountArray(Cursor cursor){
            SparseIntArray countMap=new SparseIntArray();
            while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
//now im using primitive ints
                int id=cursor.getInt(ID_INDEX);
                int count=cursor.getInt(TASK_COUNT_INDEX);
                countMap.put(id,count);
            }
            return countMap;
        }
```

Now in terms of autoboxing the primitives example should be faster, right ? Why would i want to use the first example over the second ? Are they equivilent ? Does it not do autoboxing on the Integer class so the first would be less memory efficient ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole point of [SpareIntArray](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/SparseIntArray.html), as you can tell from the javadoc, is to avoid the autoboxing of ints.  When you start doing that in code, it defeats one of the main optimizations of SparseIntArray.  So the first example provides no obvious advantage that I can see.  They are functionally equivalent, but the second example should run faster when a large number of elements are being processed.  For a small number of elements, there may be no discernable difference in speed.

Memory consumption is not an issue here as all the created Integer objects are going to be garbage collected some time after the loop completes.  The SparseIntArray is not holding any boxed Integers because they are being unboxed at the point you execute `countMap.put(id,count);`.

What's ultimately going on in the first example is that a bunch of ints are getting boxed into Integers, then immediately unboxed to get into the SparseIntArray, which is completely unnecessary.

Comment: Autoboxing isn't a problem just for memory consumption. There are an overhead in processing for allocating an Integer in every step of the loop in the first example and an overhead for the GC to dealocate the Integer. GC runs on idle, but it consumes processing and obviously energy to process. If you are running this code in the UIThread, the difference between the two examples show be enough for running above the 16 milliseconds limit.